# Android DialogFragment getActivity() is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

I am trying to create a dialog which displays the user a countdown before the user is logged out. The timeout is set from another activity.

I wrote the following code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SessionInactivityDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public void setInactivityTimeout(long timeout) {
        Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
        String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.iminent_logout_text), (timeout / 1000));
        ((AlertDialog)getDialog()).setMessage(text);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.iminent_logout);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                SessionActivity activity = (SessionActivity)getActivity();
                activity.resetTimer();
            }
        });

     return builder.create();
    }

}
```

The dialog is called with these lines:

```
private void showIminentLogoutDialog(long timeout) {
    mInactivityDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
    mInactivityDialog.setInactivityTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Even though the timeout is set after the dialog has opened, `getActivity()`  in `setInactivityTimeout()` is `null`.

How do I get the resources in the fragment correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DialogFragment.show()` is asynchronous -- the `DialogFragment` isn't actually immediately displayed -- it's sent to the end of the message queue. I'd suggest providing the timeout value as an argument, and then set it in `onCreateDialog()` along with the title. For example:

```
public class SessionInactivityDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_TIMEOUT = "timeout";

    public static SessionInactivityDialog newInstance(long timeout) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(EXTRA_TIMEOUT, timeout);
        SessionInactivityDialog dialog = new SessionInactivityDialog();
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final SessionActivity activity = (SessionActivity) getActivity();
        final long timeout = getArguments().getLong(EXTRA_TIMEOUT);
        final String msg = activity.getString(R.string.imminent_logout_text, (timeout / 1000));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.imminent_logout);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                activity.resetTimer();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Then you can just show it with:

```
SessionInactivityDialog.newInstance(timeout)
                       .show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

I'd also suggest making an interface for the dialog to communicate with the activity, rather than adding the direct dependency on `SessionActivity` (that way you can reuse this in *any* Activity, as long as it implements your interface).

Comment: But when I call newInstance, a new Dialog is created every time, I want to update the timeout. The timeout is set every second, so the user have to close as many dialogs as opened by the calling activity. If I use re-use the instance (e.g. Singleton Dialog) would this imply any other draw-backs or is it okay?

Comment: I tried the Singleton approach, but it failed. the fragement is already active and setArguments results in a `IllegalStateException`. How do I fix this? I don't want to add another `CountdownTimer` just to refresh the text inside the Dialog.

Comment: If it needs to be live updating, then the `Fragment` itself should handle the logic of counting down, and just call back to the `Activity` once the timer has run out or should be reset. Alternatively, you can call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` in your Activity after showing the dialog, and then you can call methods on the Fragment knowing that it is attached to the Activity.