# Recursive Call getSupportFragmentManager() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, recursion, android-dialogfragment

The first call of the function works, but as it tries to call itself after closing the first dialog the app crashes with

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
```

Maybe someone can help me find my error here? My assumption is that the first instance of the dialog maybe is still open when the second dialog tries to open?

```
public void displayDialog(int id) {
    currImportId = id;
    BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new MediaAddFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("formtype", MediaAddFragment.FORMTYPE_IMPORT);
    bundle.putString("name", importStreams.get(id).getName());
    bundle.putString("url", importStreams.get(id).getUrl());
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onResume();
            displayDialog(currImportId + 1);
        }
    });
    dismiss();
}
```

Kind regards,

Battlestr1k3

Comment: My guess is that is has something to do with your `dismiss();` statement at the end of the method. Should you be doing `bottomSheetDialogFragment.dismiss();`? It sounds like your error is that `getActivity()` is returning null - as if your activity doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DialogFragment getActivity() is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490687/android-dialogfragment-getactivity-is-null)

Comment: The removal of dismiss() did it, thank you guys!